# What a pronoun should one use: "you" or "yours"?

Tags: pronouns, legalese, personal-pronouns

> This document sets out the rights and responsibilities of [you || yours], the Company, and the concerned third parties.

If "the Client's rights" can be rephrased to "the rights of Client", then, I suppose, "your rights" can be rephrased to "the rights of you", but "the rights of yours" sounds greater.

So, is either variant appropriate and which should one better use?

Comment: Don't use any pronouns.  And consult a lawyer.

Comment: One problem is that "of you, the Company," could be interpreted as a parenthetical meaning that "you" are also known as "the Company".  This is the way I read it many times.  I think now what you mean is: "sets out your rights and responsibilities as well as those of the Company and the concerned third parties."  But I think the reader of this document (the "you" being referred to) ought to be named by role instead:  "... sets out the rights and responsibilities of the Client, the Company, and the concerned third parties."

Answer (score 1):

Should the sentence be: *this document sets out the rights and responsibilities of you clients, the Company's, and the concerned third parties'?*

Or

*This document sets out your rights and responsibilities, the Company's, and the concerned third parties'.*

Or

*This document sets out the clients' rights and responsibilities , the Company's, and the concerned third parties'*.

And of course @Jim advice to consult a lawyer is in proper order I must say.